# How to implement a GDB function depending on the architecture

Tags: c, gdb, cpu-architecture, gdb-python

I'm writing a `GDB` script in `python` to print some debug information of the application. The thing is multiple architectures are supported: x86, alpha, aarch64, and probably some more later. The function printing the debug information varies from the architecture.

So in fact I've got the following functions:

```
def print_info_x86():
   #...


def print_info_aarch64():
   #...


def print_info_alpha():
   #...
```

And I want to achieve something like the following:

```
def print_info():
   if arch == 'x86':
      print_info_x86()
   #etc..
```

Is there a way to do that? There is a GDB command `show architecture` and it's possible to extract it from `objdump -a`, but is there a simpler way to understand what architecture the binary was compiled for in `GDB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Architectures-In-Python.html

something like this:

```
f = gdb.selected_frame()
a = f.architecture()
print(a.name())
```

Comment: You probably meant `frame = gdb.selected_frame()`, not `f = gdb.selected_frame()`

Comment: @SomeName copy-paste copied the invokation form the documentation

Comment: I would probably use [gdb.selected_inferior().architecture().name()](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-In-Python.html#index-Inferior_002earchitecture) instead, so I don't need a running process.